# Code elegance and compactness. Help needed with Map, Apply

Tags: core-language, code-review, cluster-analysis

I need some help with code optimization and compactness.

I have a set of two-dimensional points and I can use the Mathematica function *FindClusters* to find 4 clusters.
I'd like to plot the points together with 4 circles centered at the cluster centroids and with radii equal to the average distance between the points of the cluster and its centroid.

Up to now I've come up with the following code:

```
data = {{-1.1, 2.6}, {3.9, -0.8}, {4.2, -3.7}, {3.3, 3.5}, {3.9, 
    5.2}, {4.1, -4.8}, {3.8, 3.7}, {5.6, 0.1}, {3.1, -5.2}, {-0.9, 
    2.3}, {2.9, 4.1}, {-2.3, 3.9}, {-2.5, 3.}, {2.6, -5.5}, {5.2, 
    1.9}, {-0.7, 1.3}, {0.9, 2.8}, {-1.5, 3.3}, {3.8, 
    1.2}, {2.6, -5.1}, {-0.8, 3.2}, {4.7, 0.7}, {3., 3.}, {3.9, 
    3.6}, {4.5, 1.4}, {4.2, 1.3}, {-1.1, 2.6}, {4.8, 
    2.4}, {3.3, -3.5}, {3.2, -4.6}, {3.3, -4.9}, {3., 3.5}, {0.7, 
    2.1}, {3.2, -4.3}, {-2., 0.5}, {-1.2, 2.}, {-1.6, 1.8}, {-3.5, 
    3.7}, {4.8, 0.2}, {3.3, 2.4}, {-0.1, 2.1}, {-1.3, 2.5}, {4.4, 
    3.9}, {3.5, 0.2}, {0.1, 2.9}, {-1., 1.6}, {-1.4, 4.5}, {3.2, 
    2.5}, {-1.6, 
    2.4}, {2.6, -5.1}, {-3.4, -2.5}, {-3.6, -2.4}, {-3.7, -3.0}, \
{-3.26, -3.8}, {-3.8, -2.8}, {-3.5, -3.3}};
clusterdata = 
  FindClusters[data, 4, 
   Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}];
centroids = Mean /@ clusterdata;
radii = Table[
   Mean[Map[Norm, 
     clusterdata[[j]] - 
      Table[Map[Mean, clusterdata][[j]], {Length[
         clusterdata[[j]]]}]]], {j, 1, Length[clusterdata]}];
ListPlot[clusterdata, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], 
 Epilog -> 
  Table[Circle[#1, #2] &[centroids[[k]], radii[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[clusterdata]}]]
```

[image]

It works, but I'm positive that the same output (starting from, say, the *clusterdata* list) could be gotten with a much simpler, compact and elegant code and with the wise use of the *Map* and *Apply* functions, that are not very easy to control and manage for an occasional Mathematica user like me.

My question is not only about "elegance" but it's also motivated by the fact that this snippet of code must be very much optimized since, in the project I'm working on, the plot must be dynamically updated with around 100 fast moving points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rF1 = Mean[Norm /@ Standardize[#, Mean, 1 &]] &;
rF2 = Function[{x}, Mean[Norm[# - Mean[x]] & /@ x]];

radii1 =rF1 /@ clusterdata;
radii2 = rF2 /@ clusterdata;
radii == radii1 == radii2
(* True *)

circles = Circle @@@ Thread[{centroids, radii}];

ListPlot[clusterdata, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, 
         PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03],  Epilog -> circles]
```

[image]

You can also use `Graphics`:

```
points = {#, Point@#2} & @@@ MapIndexed[{ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[#2[[1]]]], #} &, clusterdata];
pr = Round@Through@{Min, Max}@clusterdata;

Graphics[{PointSize[.03], circles, points}, PlotRange -> {pr, pr}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
clusterdata = FindClusters[data, 4, Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}];
ListPlot[clusterdata, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], 
 Epilog -> MapThread[Circle, {Mean /@ clusterdata, 1/Sqrt[2] Norm /@ Variance /@ clusterdata}]]
```

Comment: Even simpler: `Epilog -> MapThread[Circle, {centroids, radii}]`

Comment: Actually "1/Sqrt[2] Norm /@ Variance /@ clusterdata" doesn't give the mean distance to the cluster centroid as I intended, whilst kguler's function Function[{x}, Mean[Norm[# - Mean[x]] & /@ x]]; produces exactly what I intended...